# How to handle Master Page Button Click Events in the Content Page?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, master-pages

I have master page in ASP.NET.

I have  added two asp controls to master page i.e. `_EmpDROPDOWN` and `_findBUTTON`.

I have one content page. *FindEmployee.aspx* which shows result list of employees (Gridview) based on the selection made in `_EmpDROPDOWN` when `_FindBUTTON` is clicked on Master Page.
I dont know how to read Master Page button click evenet in Content page.

How to read master page button click event (VB.NET syntax) in Content Page ?

Answer (score 0):

[Page.Master Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.master.aspx) gets the master page that determines the overall look of the page.

```
MasterPageType masterPage = (MasterPageType) page.Master;
```